Polish Probability Spaces
I'm trying to prove this statement:
Let $(S,B(S), \mu)$ be a probability space and suppose $S$ is Polish ,i.e ,$S$ is complete and separable.
Then $ \forall \epsilon > 0, \forall A \in B(S), \exists K_{\epsilon} \subset A $ compact, such that: $$\mu (A - K_{\epsilon})<\epsilon $$
Consider these two results:
(1) Every measure of probability in $(S ,B(S))$ is regular;
$(\forall \epsilon > 0, \forall A \in B(S), \exists F_{\epsilon},G_{\epsilon} : F_{\epsilon}\subset A \subset G_{\epsilon}, \mu(G_{\epsilon} - F_{\epsilon})<\epsilon $ with G open and F closed).
(2) Let $(S,B(S), \mu)$ be a probability space and suppose $S$ is Polish. Then $\forall \epsilon >0 , \exists K_{\epsilon} \in B(S)$ compact, such that $\mu(K_{\epsilon})>1-\epsilon$.
My attempt:
Since $\mu$ is regular, we can find closed and open sets $F$ and $G$ which satisfy (1), but since $S$ is also Polish, we can find a compact set $K_{\epsilon}$ which satisfies (2).
Take $K=F \cap K_{\epsilon} \Rightarrow A - K = A - (K_{\epsilon}\cap F)\subset (G - F)\Rightarrow \mu(A-K)<\mu(G-F)<\epsilon$. ( If $K\neq \emptyset$)
Obs: Since $F$ is closed and $K_{\epsilon}$ is compact ( then is closed ) , then $F\cap k_{\epsilon}$ is closed. But $F\cap k_{\epsilon} \subset K_{\epsilon}$ then is also compact.
Now if $K = \emptyset$ then the sets $K_{\epsilon}$ and $F$ are disjoint, but by (2) $\mu(K_{\epsilon})>1-\epsilon \Leftrightarrow \mu(K_{\epsilon}^c)<\epsilon$, so we can choose $\epsilon$, such that, the complement of $K_{\epsilon}$ is very small, i. e , $K_{\epsilon}$ is as big as we wish.
So, we can choose $\epsilon$, such that, the sets $K_{\epsilon}$ and $F$ are not disjoint.
Is my proof correct or not?

$A - (K_{\epsilon}\cap F)\subset (G - F)$ need not hold. To see this, consider the case that $A=G$ and $K_\epsilon\cap F$ is a strict subset of $F$.
